# Can flixel or a similar engine be used with reddwarf server?

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3

I like the sgs/projectdarkstar or now known as reddwarf server for a back end game server.  However I am looking for a good front end, preferably 2D.  I was thinking of something such as flixel.  I know there is an AS3 library available for reddwarf, so I am hoping someone already has connected up flixel or a similar engine?   Or if you have a recommendation for another easy client side engine that will connect to reddwarf?

Comment: What kind of integration into the game-engine are you looking for? You should probably be more specific about your requirements there.

Answer (score 1):

Flixel and your client engine don't 'connect' to each other.  They are both libraries YOU have to integrate into your flash.

Think of flixel more like a box of pencil crayons, and your client library like a phone cord.  Alone they don't do anything.  It's how you use them that makes your game what it it.

Also judging by the rough bounds of this question I might recommend you scale down your first project of this nature.  Server/Client interactions are a hefty challenge on their own, without any graphics ever being involved.  But before you ever try that, make a full game, start to finish with flixel, *then* add new technologies.  If you can't be patient enough to take the time to do that, you will have serious trouble ever finishing this project.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'client engine' - I am referring to a server.   I do not want to re-invent the wheel and develop my own client/server protocol stacks.   I do not want hammer and nails, I am looking for modular housing.  People have been developing multiplayer games for many years now, so I was hoping by now there would exist a reasonably decent combination of client/server gaming framework (for flash) out there already.

Comment: @Scott: You would think that, but the only systems that provide the level of modularity you are looking for starts at a pretty price, and even still would probably just be _MORE_ complicated then if you were to write one yourself.  Client side socket actions in AS3 take about 40 lines of code.  I've also written a server (that manages mySQL backend) in C#.  Since every game is different, and needs to send different data, you will always have to write a protocol of some kind.  Worry more about the game itself, not servers and money making and it will all fall into place.

Comment: @Scott: After doing a bit more digging into the topic, it seems there are a small handful of niche server/client architectures available at a price.  The majority of the open source seems to be AS2 only.
When you build a server/client system, you aren't really re-inventing the wheel, but rather building one from wheel parts.